# Использование наследников в коллекции

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Есть некий пользовательский контрол. У него есть свойство с коллекцией элементов типа `abstract class MyClass : DependencyObject`

Есть несколько наследников этого класса (например `MyClassEx : MyClass`)

Так вот, когда я в xaml разметке добавляю в коллекцию новый элемент вот так

```
<MyControl>
    <MyControl.SomeCollection>
        <MyClassEx/>
    </MyControl.SomeCollection>
</MyControl>
```

то при запуске все норм, но в режиме дизайнера `<MyClassEx/>` подчеркнуто и при наведении выходит "Указанное значение нельзя присвоить коллекции. Требуется следующий тип: "MyClass".

Это немного напрягает. подскажите как вылечить? Может атрибут какой нужен к коллекции, чтобы xaml позволял безболезненно использовать в коллекции наследников?

Comment: А какого типа `SomeCollection`?

Comment: @VladD, `SomeCollection : DependencyObject, INotifyCollectionChanged, IList, IList<MyClass>`

Comment: Хм. А если попробовать добавить атрибут `[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]`?

Comment: @VladD, хм.... вылечилось удалением типа `DependencyObject` из объявления типа `SomeCollection`. Не знаю почему... у меня нет времени разбираться, но если вы найдете причину, оформите в ответ пожалуйста

Comment: @VladD, ошибочка вышла... Конец рабочего дня и все такое... запарился. В общем тип коллекции `ObservableCollection<MyClass>`.